# Decorating a class that inherits a protected observable

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance, anti-patterns, javafx-8

Let's say I want to decorate a class that inherits a protected observable field. How can I gain access to that protected variable so I can extend the said superclass' functionality?

Please see a more specific example below.

**Class SuperSuper** - The class that originally contains the anonymous observer

```
package javafxapplication1;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SuperSuper extends Application {

    protected Button button = new Button();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                doSomething();
            }
        });
    }

    public String doSomething() {
        return "1";
    }
}
```

**Class Super** - The superclass that inherits the anonymous observer

```
package javafxapplication2;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafxapplication1.SuperSuper;

public class Super extends SuperSuper {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                doSomething();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public String doSomething() {
        return "2";
    }
}
```

**Class SuperDecorator** - Super's decorator class

```
package javafxapplication3;

import javafxapplication2.Super;


class SuperDecorator extends Super {
    Super zuper;

    public SuperDecorator(Super zuper){
        this.zuper = zuper;
    }

    @Override
    public String doSomething() {
        return zuper.doSomething()+"3";
    }

    //What should I put here in order to make zuper's button print 3?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//What should I put here in order to make zuper's button print 3?
```

To achieve your requirement, you don't need `Super` decoration only `extends` should work fine:

```
class SuperDecorator extends Super {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("3");
    }
}
```

and then call `new SuperDecorator().doSomething()`

Ideally decorator implementation should go via `interface`, your modified approach is right though `extends` still doesn't work well as how would you be using inheritance during decoration since methods are delegated to `zuper` and result modified (`decorated`). Consider following alternate:

```
public class SuperSuper extends Application implements IActionPerformer {
            @Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            doSomething();
        }
    });
}

        public String doSomething() {
            return "1";
        }
    }

    public class Super extends SuperSuper {
        public String doSomething() {
            return "2";
        }
    }

    abstract class AbstractSuperDecorator implements IActionPerformer {
        protected IActionPerformer zuper;
        public AbstractSuperDecorator(IActionPerformer zuper) {
            this.zuper = zuper;
        }
        public String doSomething() {
            return zuper.doSomething();
        }
    }

    public class Super3Decorator extends AbstractSuperDecorator {
        public Super3Decorator(IActionPerformer zuper) {
            super(zuper);
        }
        public String doSomething() {
            return super.doSomething()+"some-val"; //decoration
        }
    }
```

**Note:** Understand this difference that your decoration is around `doSomething` which is moved out to an `interface`, not around `start` or `button`. `start` dependency on `doSomething` is implicit (implementation driven) and it's not a decoration participant.

Comment: Hi harsh, thanks for pointing out on the requirement. I edited the question so that the codes will be fit for a decorator. Now, when I use "extends" I can access "button" but when I decorate Super, I cannot access "button" anymore. Is this a case where I still shouldn't be using decoration?

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer. I'm a little razzed though, because in your given case I won't be able to observe button. I won't be able to display a screen anymore in that case because I can't extend Application.